# adding inline-block divs moves parent to the bottom of the screen

Tags: html, sass

I have 2 divs (`.showcase`, `.highlight`) nested inside an element with `position: relative`:

I would like to have a margin on the left of the .contentContainer for the navigation menu (23.79%). Then I would like 2 divs inside the contentContainer div that extend the whole height of the screen, regardless of their content. Then I would like to add content inside those two divs.

```
<div id="App">
  <div data-reactroot="">
    <div class="navbarContainer">
    </div>
    <div class="contentContainer">
      <div class="showcase">
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="highlight"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now when I add more divs into my showcase div, the `.showcase` div gets moved to the bottom of the screen (so only the 100px of the `.thumb` divs are visible.). I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Stylesheet:

```
#App {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: $fontC2;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
}
.contentContainer {
  margin-left: 23.79%;
  width: 76.21%;
  height: 100vh;
  .showcase {
    width: 61%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    .thumb {
      width: 20%;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: $primaryC3;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
  .highlight {
    width: 39%;
    background-color: $primaryC2;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/2tz9940v/

Comment: Can you re do this issue in JSfiddle?

Comment: added to question

Comment: The problem seems to be with the height property on showcase and highlight. When this is not set to full browser window, everything works fine.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve, it would help if you could add a mockup

Comment: @ovokuro sorry added a description to the question. Basically just 2 divs that always have a height of the whole screen, and some content inside.

Comment: Try adding vertical-align:top to the showcase div